# boostrap: why is my navbar logo crashed against the left edge of the viewport?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using Bootstrap 3.x and have a navbar with a logo on the left that is working great on desktop:

[image]

**[The dark rectangle is standing in for the logo.]**

Now the issue is that, when the viewport grows narrower and the navbar switches to collapsed mode, the logo is pushed all the way against the left edge of the viewport:

[image]

**QUESTION: How can I keep a small gap between the left edge of the viewport and the logo on mobile?** If I simply add a margin-left or padding-left to the logo itself, that will also apply in the first cenario (ie, on a desktop) and break the current alignment of the logo with the edge of the main container on the page.

**CODE:**

```
<html>
<body>

    <!-- This navigation bar should be replicated across all site pages. 
    On each page, remember to move the "active" class to the <li> element that points to
    the current page.-->

    <div id="navigation_bar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-left" href="/"><img id="logo_navbar" height="110px" src="/img/logo-test-bg.png"></a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>
        <div id="navigation_bar_rhs" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">2</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>


<div id="main_container" class="container">

   <div class="row"> <!-- 1st row -->
   </div> <!-- end of 1st row -->
</div> <!-- end of main_container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .navbar-left {
         margin-left: 10px;
        }
    }
```

**Just replace 480 with other value if you want to have the margin on higher viewport.**
working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyYdmQ?editors=1100)

Comment: this would be fine @lara

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to research media queries and use max-width with your nav-bar class.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 .nav-bar brand {
         padding: 5%;
         margin-left: 5%;
        }
    }
```

Instead of specifying the device that it's used on you are specifying the width of the screen.

[MDN Explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: thank you for this but it is not working. Did you mean the class "navbar-brand"? I am using navbar-left and even after I replace one by the other I still don't get a gap on the left for a viewport < 480px-wide.

Comment: in your code it would be `navbar-left` it looks like. Bootstrap prefers you to use the brand instead.

Comment: Also, I recommend using a Chrome plugin: [link] (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-width/mlnegepkjlccabakompdmbcmdieaideh?hl=en-US). It will help you figure out the exact value. 480 may not be quite correct.